# Android NDK does not react on change

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am implementing Android camera app where I am processing preview frames in JNI. I have processImage.cpp file where I do all the native processing and it worked until now when I have discovered that if I do any change to the native file, it does not change the behaviour of the app.

Maybe it could be connected to the **static linking of OpenCV library** that I've added recently and where I load the native library.

```
package fit.vutbr.faceswap;

// OpenCV static initialization
    static {
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            // Handle initialization error
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV init error");
        }
        else {
            System.loadLibrary("processImage");
            //System.loadLibrary("detection_based_tracker");
        }
    }
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# OpenCV
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
include C:\Users\Acer\Projects\OpenCV\OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_C_INCLUDE:= C:\Users\Acer\Projects\OpenCV\OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ldl
LOCAL_MODULE    := processImage  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := processImage.cpp 



include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_MODULES := processImage
```

**Declaration** of the native method:

```
private native int[] kalmanFilterNative(int center_x, int center_y);
```

**Definition** in processImage.cpp:

```
jintArray Java_fit_vutbr_faceswap_CameraPreview_kalmanFilterNative( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jint center_x, jint center_y) 
{                   
  // code
  return ret;
}
```

And on call `ret = kalmanFilterNative(center_x, center_y);` I get `UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found`.

Does anybody have a clue where is the problem?

Comment: Probably a cashe problem. Delete the apk from the project directory, and also uninstall the app from the device.

Comment: still getting: "W/dalvikvm(6553): No implementation found for native Lfit/vutbr/faceswap/CameraPreview;.kalmanFilterNative:(II)[I"

Comment: I have encountered situations when C++ build failed, but I did not notice this.

Comment: I ran `ndk-build` manually and it turned out there was an error. After correcting it the build was finished.

But now after running `ndk-build` I've lost my **opencv_java.so** from libs directory (I am using static init as I mentioned above). Is it possible to build them at once?

Comment: ok, issue solved :) I've just edited Android.mk according to this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization).

Could you answer my question and I will mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your native method to :

```
extern "C" {
    JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_fit_vutbr_faceswap_CameraPreview_kalmanFilterNative( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jint center_x, jint center_y);
};
    JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_fit_vutbr_faceswap_CameraPreview_kalmanFilterNative( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jint center_x, jint center_y) 
    {                   
      // code
      return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I forgot to include `extern "C" {JNIEXPORT ... JNICALL}` in my original question but I have that in my code :) anyway I've solved it as you can see in the comments.